# Not able to run Django project on local machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am new to Django and I want to run a project in my local machine but it gives errors. Let me describe it:

**manage.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys

from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render
from django.template import loader
from django.urls import reverse

import traceback
def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "lmui.settings")

    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    try:
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    except Exception as e: 
        print(str(e))
    except:
        print("Oops!", sys.exc_info()[0], "occurred.")
        message = traceback.format_exc()
        print(message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I run the the project as below on git bash:

```
>> python manage.py migrate
   Segmentation fault

>> python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
   Watching for file changes with StatReloader
   Performing system checks...

   Oops! <class 'SystemExit'> occurred.
```

and traceback error is:

```
File "C:\Users\rakesh.client\OneDrive - client\Documents\Rakesh\client\projects\codes\myproject\lmui-django\manage.py", line 25, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\rakesh.client\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\rakesh.client\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\rakesh.client\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\rakesh.client\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\rakesh.client\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\rakesh.client\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 96, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\rakesh.client\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 103, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\rakesh.client\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 641, in run_with_reloader
    sys.exit(exit_code)
SystemExit: 3221225477
```

Python version: Python 3.10.5 and Django version: 3.2.6

I have added try except to catch the error but it does not print exception error but it goes to another except block and print the traceback.

EDIT:
settings.py file database code:

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified Port and Host correctly in your database settings? (DATABASES={...} ). Port and Host should not be empty, if you have no value for them they should not be defined at all.

Also, since some libraries (mostly C) links themselves with system libraries, you may want to delete and reinstall the virtual environment if you did a system update.

Comment: I have edited my question and added the database configuration code also. What will be port and host for my database and how to add it on my local? and I haven't update the system.

Comment: if you are using SQLite it is not necessary to specify them (it is already local). Did you do any system update before running the project?

Comment: no I did not do any system update. If I did not add any try except block it just break the runserver execution without any errors.